# how to append a column header using sed $ delimited

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have an input file like this

```bash
$col1$col2$col3
$col1data$col2data$col3data
```

I want to add $col4 header after $col3

so I'm trying to do a

`sed -i "s/$col3/$col3$col4/"`

...to add a col4 header

my loops add the 4th column of data alright already, so I just need to modify the header, 1st line.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: precede `s///` by a line number to only affect that line. eg: `1s/.../.../`

Comment: You use double quotes in your sed command. This means that the shell interprets `col3` and `col4` as variables and expands them, before passing the argument to sed. You can observe the effect by doing a `set -x` before running the command.

Comment: Why not simply `sed '1s/$/$col4/'` ? Note that the first `$` has a special meaning in sed expression: it denotes the end-of-line when used as an anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Using dollar signs as delimiters is a stupendously poor choice because they have a special meaning both to `sed` and to the shell. You can avoid the latter by using single quotes instead of double, but you will still need to backslash every literal dollar sign.

To only perform an action on the first line, add the line number as a condition.

```
sed -i '1s/\$col3/$col3$col4/' file
```

If you stick to double quotes, you'll need to backslash each dollar sign multiple times, to the point of being hard to understand or manipulate.